# Redirect URLs ASP.net core, Google Searches

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, redirect

My website was formerly implemented with ASP.net. I reimplemented it using ASP.net core. It is hosted by a different hosting service but the domain name is the same. The URLs to the pages have changed. For example:

old URL: https://www.roberttayloronline.com/Trips/2019PineRiverTrail/2019PineRiverTrail.aspx

new URL: https://roberttayloronline.com/recreation/trips/2019-pine-river-trail

When I use Google search for "Pine River Trail, Weminuche Wilderness", Google shows the old aspx URL. I have submitted a new sitemap using the Google Search Console. I see how to remove the old URL from Google, but I want Google to redirect it, not remove it.

I cannot figure out how to instruct Google search to make this change. Is this possible?

I also thought I might be able to deal with this issue by redirecting the URLs with my website by including code like this in Configure method in the startup.cs file:

```
var rewriteOptions = new RewriteOptions().AddRedirect(
    @"(?i)(\/Trips\/2019PineRiverTrail\/2019PineRiverTrail\.aspx)",
    "https://roberttayloronline.com/recreation/trips/2019-pine-river-trail",
    (int)HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently);
applicationBuilder.UseRewriter(rewriteOptions);
```

but I am not getting that to work. I get a 404 error with the old URL.

Would someone point me in the right direction.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find a way to directly instruct Google to redirect the old URLs.

Putting code such as this in my website's web.config file will redirect the URLs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="rule-01" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="Trips\/2019PineRiverTrail\/2019PineRiverTrail\.aspx" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://roberttayloronline.com/recreation/trips/2019-pine-river-trail" redirectType="Permanent" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

More information can be seen here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference